# Django Admin Problem Coercing to Unicode

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Trying to create a Django app based off the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/) but using a different model.(First time using Djanago)

I'm at the part where you alter the Admin panel to add 3 items with a dependent foreign key.

I know the problem originates from the

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
```

on line 10 of admin.py but I'm not sure how the fields should be arranged to make it work.

The admin panel works untill I try to create an event with 3 choices. Then I get the following error... **coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Location found**

Code is as follows...

## models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Location(models.Model):
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.location

class Event(models.Model):
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
    info = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.location

class Choice(models.Model):
    event = models.ForeignKey(Event)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    link = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

## admin.py

```
from map.models import Location
from map.models import Event
from map.models import Choice
from django.contrib import admin

class ChoiceInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 4

class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
             (None,               {'fields': ['location', 'info']}),
             ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]

admin.site.register(Event, EventAdmin)
admin.site.register(Location)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.__unicode__()` method is expected to return a `unicode` object.

Your `Event.__unicode__()` however returns `self.location` which is a `Location` instance. Either have it cast `self.location` to `unicode` or explicitly reference a field in the `Location` object.

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % (self.location, )

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.location.location
```

Comment: +1. And think returning self.location.location is a bad form - first example with conversion of Location to unicode string is preferable.